# Как найти расстояние между двумя CLLocationCoordinate2DMake

Tags: swift

Есть две точки

```
let locationA = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(62.028850, 119.734073)
let locationB = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.028850, 88.734073)
```

Как узнать расстояние между ними в метрах (может есть какие-нибудь специальные функции)?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.8F.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B4.D1.83_.D0.B4.D0.B2.D1.83.D0.BC.D1.8F_.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.81.D1.84.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5

Comment: https://github.com/VAndrJ/Coordinates-To-Distance-Swift

Comment: @VAndrJ скопируйте снипет в ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
     func distanceTo(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
            let thisLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
            let otherLocation = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
            return thisLocation.distanceFromLocation(otherLocation)
      }
}
```

Сделай такое расширение для CLLocationCoordinate2D

Использовать таким образом:

```
locationA.distanceTo(locationB)
```

Вернет расстояние в метрах